# Multiple inserts happening at the same time SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the problem that I'm getting multiple inserted rows where only 1 row should be inserted.

I have a procedure similar to this but the procedure is being executed multiple times with the same input parameters at the same moment by different sources so we are getting multiple duplicated lines with the same data.

Edit: more info, we are getting multiple different events and each event might execute this procedure if it has a new server_id that has not been added to the table before. Sometimes we get multiple events that all have the same server_id which has not yet been entered into the database so they all try to enter it into the db with this procedure at the same time and we get multiple rows in the table

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [stuff].[p_insert_missing_data]
    @in_event_timestamp DATETIME2(7),
    @in_source_system   NVARCHAR(50),
    @in_server_id       NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO house.servers (
        xtract_datetime, 
        xtract_source, 
        server_id
    )
    SELECT GETDATE()           AS xtract_datetime,
           @in_source_system   AS xtract_source,
           @in_server_id       AS server_id
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM house.servers WHERE server_id = @in_server_id)
END
```

Comment: "the procedure is being executed multiple times with the same input parameters at the same moment by different sources" --> so seems logical that you have multiple inserts? Can you explain the problem in more detail?

Comment: More information added

Comment: Try `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM house.servers WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE) WHERE ...` - this should prevent multiple inserts for the exact same `server_id` at the exact same time from slipping in between the check and the insert. Works best of course if there is a (unique) index on `server_id` and if there aren't 1,000 other indexes that have to be updated as part of the insert.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I can never get my head round this: if using `SERIALIZABLE` in a `SELECT` (non-modifying reference) do we or do we not need `UPDLOCK`?

Comment: @Charlieface I can't always get my head around it either, it's [how I've always written it](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern) and it works, is it 8 more characters than I might need? Maybe. With a single statement it's less important, I think, than if it is involved in a larger transaction.

Comment: @Charlieface I believe... In the context here of inserting a row that does not exist if two concurrent transactions arrive for the same `server_id` that does not exist then `UPDLOCK` will mean that only one of them gets the range lock and the other one has to wait and will then silently determine the row now exists and so not attempt an insert. Whereas with just SERIALIZABLE they can both get a shared range lock and then proceed to deadlock. So the net effect is that both options end up insert a row but one option will also end up aborting an attempt with an error.

Comment: (and end up injecting a delay before the deadlock monitor notices the deadlock)

Comment: @MartinSmith So you are saying that `UPDLOCK` is necessary but only for deadlock prevention? Whereas under `REPEATABLE READ` or lower then a range lock is not taken anyway, and under `READ COMMITTED` it would not be held without `UPDLOCK` so it would be even more necessary then?

Comment: That the `SERIALIZABLE`/`HOLDLOCK` is needed to lock the range where the non existent row would exist. And that the `UPDLOCK` is just to do this in a way that is not deadlock prone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure you do not get any chance of a race condition, where multiple processes try to insert the same row, you need `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level. You can set this on the whole procedure, or better is to add an explicit hint to just that table reference `WITH (SERIALIZABLE)` or `WITH (HOLDLOCK)`. The server will then place a key range lock, which not only locks that key, it also locks the *absence* of the key. It will also hold that lock to the end of the transaction (statement if no transaction).

This has the downside that there is more locking, increasing the risk of deadlocks. Therefore you should also add a `UPDLOCK` hint.

```sql
 INSERT INTO house.servers (
     xtract_datetime, 
     xtract_source, 
     server_id
 )
 SELECT GETDATE(),
        @in_source_system,
        @in_server_id
 WHERE
     NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
         FROM house.servers s WITH (SERIALIZABLE, UPDLOCK)
         WHERE s.server_id = @in_server_id);
```

You do not need a transaction, as every statement implicitly runs in its own transaction anyway.

For this to only place a key lock, and not lock the whole table up, you also need an index. This can either be clustered or non-clustered, although `server_id` I'm guessing is the primary key, therefore should normally be clustered anyway.

```sql
house.servers (server_id ASC)
```